# Reducing the density of points based on zoom level

Tags: leaflet, point, markers, density, generalization

I have a Polyline like the one shown in the example, representing the path of a vehicle. GeoJSON markers show the vehicle's position over time.

How can I reduce the density of the markers when the user zooms out?

[image]

[Example with Polyline Decorator](http://bbecquet.github.io/Leaflet.PolylineDecorator/example/example.html)

Comment: Can you please clarify what should happen to the markers when the user zooms in? What should happen when the user zooms out?

Comment: As the user zooms in, the hidden markers are displayed and as he moves away he is hiding only a part of them so that the Polyline does not look as over loaded.

The idea is to make a kind of cluster.

Comment: Have you looked at the [Leaflet marker cluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) functionality? If so, what needs to be different than using that library?

Comment: I have seen some examples but the examples are oriented grouping the markers and I really need to not group them rather hide it.
[ejemplo](https://ibb.co/gohOGv)
The image shows 3 zoom levels 12, 14, 16 as an example.

Comment: the example link isn't working for me. Can you edit the question and include the 3 images directly in the Stack Exchange question?

Comment: thanks, that makes a lot more sense now. What do the markers represent? Are they physical locations (for example, bus stops) or do they represent something abstract?  Is it important which of the markers will be dropped when you zoom out? Or do you simply need to remove a proportion of markers?

Comment: Represents a moving vehicle.
This is a history of his movements.
I need to hide a proportion not to saturate the view of the user.

Comment: another question - what is the format of the markers? For example, are they GeoJSON, WFS, etc?

Comment: GeoJSON.
I'm thinking of making use of Polyline Decorator plugin I really believe that there is my answer. it is not necessary to show all the markers on the map.
I will show their detail in a table and when the user hover in one of them I move a marker to that position with its details.

Comment: @chap2 did you find a solution? I have a similar issue. I found Polyline Decorator plugin generates more markers than there are in the data.

Comment: @LawrenceWlt hello, as the name implies the plugin is a Polyline decorator, you can reduce the amount of markers it shows you based on the length of your data.